# How to handle string comparison?

Tags: string, rust

I'm currently reading a file and need to compare the first line against a hardcoded value. I'm doing this:

```
let mut file = BufferedReader::new(File::open(path));
let mut first: bool = true;
for a_line in file.lines() {
    let line = a_line.unwrap();
    if first &&  line.as_slice() != "[tag]" {
        println!("Returning None");
        return None;
    }
    first = false;
}
```

I know `first` is true and `println!("{}", line)` shows it to be `"[tag]"` but the comparison always seems to return false. What am I missing?

Comment: The comparison operators are the traditional ==

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a newline character in your line string. You can use the `trim` method and its variations on the string before taking a slice of it.

Comment: Still learning the language so things like this can get out of hand.